# Lead with Sum in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is schema of db

```
CREATE TABLE `visita_prodotto`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   `prezzo` int(15) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'price',
  `id_visita` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'visit id');


  CREATE TABLE `visita`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_campagna` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'project',
  `dataorainizio` datetime(0) NOT NULL COMMENT 'start date');

INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (53, 8, 5000);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (54, 8, 8000);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (55, 9, 4000);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (56, 9, 3000);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (66, 11, 5544);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (71, 12, 7500);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (77, 13, 5433);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (85, 17, 7200);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (89, 15, 4500);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (94, 16, 3200);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (99, 16, 5800);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (104, 16, 99999);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (107, 22, 7500);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (111, 22, 129999);
INSERT INTO `visita_prodotto`(`id`, `id_visita`, `prezzo`) VALUES (113, 22, 99999);

INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (8, '2020-02-12 15:23:00', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (9, '2020-02-14 01:59:45', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (11, '2020-02-19 14:27:17', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (12, '2020-02-19 15:43:42', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (13, '2020-02-20 14:02:35', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (15, '2020-02-25 15:58:00', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (16, '2020-02-21 15:59:00', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (17, '2020-02-21 16:13:00', 5);
INSERT INTO  `visita`(`id`, `dataorainizio`, `id_campagna`) VALUES (22, '2020-03-12 15:11:00', 5);
```

I have this query

```
 SELECT YEAR(v.dataorainizio) AS Year, WEEK(v.dataorainizio) AS Week, ROUND(sum(prezzo)/1000,2) as total_price
FROM visita_prodotto vp 
join visita v on vp.id_visita=v.id
where YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)<=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) and  YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)>=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-10 and v.id_campagna=5
GROUP BY Year, Week
order by Week desc
```

which produces this result

```
YEAR    WEEK TOTAL_PRICE
2020    10   237,50
2020    8    4,50
2020    7    134,68
2020    6    20,00
```

I would like to have

```
YEAR    WEEK TOTAL_PRICE DIFFERENCE
2020    10   237,50        233
2020    8    4,50          -130,18
2020    7    134,68        114,68
2020    6    20,00
```

I've tried with sum(lead),
without success..

relevant tables structure

first table visita_prodotto

```
 id      id_visita                 prezzo
 int pk  int(related to visita)    int
```

join table visita:

```
id     dataorainizio id_campagna
int pk datetime      int
```

I'm using MARIADB 10.2

can anyone help me?

thank you

Comment: Can you also post the structure (relevant columns) of the two tables you are JOINing.

Comment: Which mysql version are you using? mysql 8 has windiw functions for that. Mysql 5.x uses session variables to make such qierys

Comment: sorry for incomplete information...this is my first post in SO..I've edited the post with relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT YEAR(v.dataorainizio) AS Year, 
                     WEEK(v.dataorainizio) AS Week, 
                     ROUND(sum(prezzo)/1000,2) as total_price
              FROM visita_prodotto vp 
              join visita v on vp.id_visita=v.id
              where YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)<=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) 
                and YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)>=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-10 
                and v.id_campagna=5
              GROUP BY Year, Week )
SELECT `Year`, 
       `Week`, 
       total_price, 
       total_price - LAG(total_price) OVER (ORDER BY `Year`, `Week`) difference
/* or  total_price - LEAD(total_price) OVER (ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `Week` DESC) difference */
FROM cte
ORDER BY Year DESC, Week DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1d06fe6dbd3617175c1c2117db85c89b)

Comment: thank you for your soluton...this query run 
"Year" "Week" "total_price" "difference"
"2020" "10"   "230" 
"2020" "8"         "4.5"         "225.5"
"2020" "7"         "127.48"     "-122.98"
"2020" "6"        "20"                 "107.48"

but the result is different ..i need to  have "difference" on the same row (ex:
"Year" "Week" "total_price" "difference"
"2020" "10"   "230"          "225.5"
"2020" "8"         "4.5"          "-122.98" 
"2020" "7"         "127.48"            "107.48" 
"2020" "6"        "20"

Comment: @AlessioM. You have not provided source data fiddle.

Comment: Added structure and sample data

Comment: thank you...I think this solution is simple and elegant thank you

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You will need a subquery, like

```
SELECT YEAR(v.dataorainizio) AS Year, WEEK(v.dataorainizio) AS Week, ROUND(sum(prezzo)/1000,2) as total_price, t2.tp - ROUND(sum(prezzo)/1000,2) 
FROM visita_prodotto vp 
join visita v on vp.id_visita=v.id
join (
    SELECT ROUND(sum(prezzo)/1000,2) as tp
    FROM visita_prodotto vp2 
    join visita v2 on vp2.id_visita=v2.id
    where YEARWEEK(v2.dataorainizio,1)<=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) and  YEARWEEK(v2.dataorainizio,1)>=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-10 and v2.id_campagna=5
    GROUP BY YEAR(v2.dataorainizio), WEEK(v2.dataorainizio)
    HAVING (YEAR(v.dataorainizio) > YEAR(v2.dataorainizio)) OR ((YEAR(v.dataorainizio) = YEAR(v2.dataorainizio)) AND (WEEK(v.dataorainizio) > WEEK(v2.dataorainizio)))
    ORDER BY YEAR(v2.dataorainizio) desc, WEEK(v2.dataorainizio) desc
    LIMIT 0, 1
) t2
where YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)<=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) and  YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)>=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-10 and v.id_campagna=5
GROUP BY Year, Week, t2.tp
order by Week desc
```

The subquery selects a single group, being earlier than the current group and then does the subtraction. I don't have a database example. If you are still struggling, then create a SQL Fiddle and share the link here in the comment section.

Comment: thank you for your solution. this query generate this result 1054 - Unknown column 'Year2' in 'order clause'

Comment: @AlessioM. thanks for pointing that out. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you  1054 - Unknown column 'Year2' in 'group statement'

Comment: thank you for your solution...I've voted for LEAD solution but this solution is nice. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEAD() window function like this:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(v.dataorainizio) AS Year, 
  WEEK(v.dataorainizio) AS Week, 
  ROUND(SUM(prezzo)/1000,2) as total_price,
  LEAD(ROUND(SUM(prezzo)/1000,2)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(v.dataorainizio), WEEK(v.dataorainizio)) - ROUND(SUM(prezzo)/1000,2) difference
FROM visita_prodotto vp 
JOIN visita v ON vp.id_visita=v.id
WHERE YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)<=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) AND YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)>=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-10 AND v.id_campagna=5
GROUP BY Year, Week
ORDER BY Week desc
```

It seems that MariaDB does not support nesting aggregate functions inside window functions, so do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    YEAR(v.dataorainizio) AS Year, 
    WEEK(v.dataorainizio) AS Week, 
    ROUND(SUM(prezzo)/1000,2) AS total_price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(v.dataorainizio) DESC, WEEK(v.dataorainizio) DESC) AS rn
  FROM visita_prodotto vp 
  JOIN visita v ON vp.id_visita=v.id
  WHERE YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)<=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) AND YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1)>=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-10 AND v.id_campagna=5
  GROUP BY Year, Week
)
SELECT c1.Year, c1.Week, c1.total_price,
  c1.total_price - c2.total_price AS difference
FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2
ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
ORDER BY c1.Year DESC, c1.Week DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=38ac4589d27d52fc116222756a551bd8).
Results:

```
> Year | Week | total_price | difference
> ---: | ---: | ----------: | ---------:
> 2020 |   10 |      237.50 |     233.00
> 2020 |    8 |        4.50 |    -130.18
> 2020 |    7 |      134.68 |     114.68
> 2020 |    6 |       20.00 |     null
```

Comment: tank you for your response, this query generate an error:  4018 - No order list in window specification for 'lead'

Comment: Tested for MySql 8.0 without any errors: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ww2DMNFtMqQJxUk1qvHWqr/1

Comment: @AlessioM. check my 2nd query and the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Exclusively for versions of MySQL older than yours...

```
SELECT n.yw
     , n.total
     , ROUND(n.delta,2) delta 
  FROM  
     ( SELECT a.* 
            , @prev := total-@prev delta
            , @prev := total 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dataorainizio,'%Y-%u') yw
                   , SUM(prezzo)/1000 total 
                FROM visita v 
                JOIN visita_prodotto vp 
                  ON vp.id_visita = v.id 
               GROUP 
                  BY yw
            ) a
            , (SELECT @prev:=null) vars ORDER BY yw
     ) n 
 ORDER 
    BY yw DESC;
+---------+----------+---------+
| yw      | total    | delta   |
+---------+----------+---------+
| 2020-11 | 237.4980 |  233.00 |
| 2020-09 |   4.5000 | -130.18 |
| 2020-08 | 134.6760 |  114.68 |
| 2020-07 |  20.0000 |    NULL |
+---------+----------+---------+
```